# Why is apple authentication is failing due to unknown reason in my development build on my actual device?

Tags: react-native, oauth, expo, apple-authentication

To setup my apple authentication on my expo app, I have followed these steps:

1. Installed `expo-apple-authentication`
2. in my app.json I added these lines:

```
    "plugins": [
      "expo-router",
      "expo-apple-authentication",
    "ios": {
      "usesAppleSignIn": true,
```

3. In my code im using this button:

```
         <AppleAuthentication.AppleAuthenticationButton
           onPress={async () => {
             try {
               const credential = await AppleAuthentication.signInAsync({
                 requestedScopes: [
                   AppleAuthentication.AppleAuthenticationScope.FULL_NAME,
                   AppleAuthentication.AppleAuthenticationScope.EMAIL,
                 ],
               });
```

And it causes error on my device, when i press this button and when I log the error this is what i get:

```
  [Error: The authorization attempt failed for an unknown reason]
```

What is the reason for it? Would this work on real application?

Comment: Were you able to find a solution to this issue?

Comment: Both on simulator and real device? @lightstrike Any ideas?